# How Should I phrase a request?

Tags: user-centered-design, users, question-answer

I am creating a HTML form and I was wondering how I should phrase the request in order to help create a comfortable, credible environment for the user.

So far I have

```
What Type of Cancer Are You Interested In?
```

and

```
And What Type of Data Are You Focusing On?
```

Comment: What is this form used for? More context needed.

Comment: @AmitJain My co-worker would like to see the number of matched normal and tumor patients for a particular cancer. When they select a particular cancer, for example Breast Invasive Carcinoma, I would like to show them the number of matched normal and tumor patients for that cancer.

Comment: Are the answers obtained via multiple-choice from fixed lists of possible responses? If so, you could simplify it, e.g. `I am interested in: [selector list of cancers], With data type [selector list of data types]`

Comment: Is it between "What type of cancer...." OR ""What type of data..." ? you are concerned about the sensitiveness of the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A system should map to user goals, mental models and terms.

As you have stated:

> "My co-worker would like to see... for a particular cancer"

Seems to me highly appropriate to use 'cancer' in the caption?

Data is *very* generic. I assume your users will be experts, but still, the first alternative is far clearer as to what will happen next compared to the second one.

As others have commented, more context would be useful. A balsamic mockup perhaps?